# Which dihydroindenyl cation is the most stabilised?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I am facing difficulty in the following problem.

The carbocation which is most stabilised among the following is …

[image]

In my view c) should be most stabilised because even if one hydrogen is abstracted it will help in restoring the aromatic character. However my book gives the answer as a).

Comment: "extent of delocalisation"?

Comment: @EashaanGodbole oh yes,I did not think about that.a) is more delocalised than c).thanks.

Comment: @aniline [You may answer your own question.](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) However, we are looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Do not just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The carbocation a) is mostly stabilised because it has maximum resonance structures which leads to maximum delocalisation of the charge.

[image]

None of the others has so many resonance structures.Therefore a) is most stable.

Comment: You *could* improve this self-answer by adding that c) is only diallylic while b) is monoallylic and d) is nonstabilised with the corresponding resonance structures ;) But happy hat.